# Schengen: Booked flight tickets but no appointment in the embassy

Tags: visas, schengen

I have some questions regarding the Schengen visa. I know you need to apply the Schengen visa form the country you either stay the longest or you visit first, which for me is Italy.

But what would you do or advice me to do if I can't get an appointment in time? I bought my tickets already (I Know it's dumb), and I am suppose to fly out by June 28th, but the Italy embassy doesn't have any. appointment open until July. What should I do here? I contacted the Italian embassy, but I haven't heard anything back from them yet.

Comment: You should change or cancel your tickets, if it will not be very expensive.

Comment: It's non refundable, so it would be really expensive. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing else that can be done. It is the start of the busy summer travel season so extraordinary delays are expected at embassy.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to split your time between Italy and a neighboring country and apply there instead.

Comment: Wow. I was in the same boat few weeks back. Keep looking at the appointment slots as if you are lucky, someone might cancel and you can grab the slot. I was able to book a slot for Monday on Sunday morning. I know it is too late for this trip but for future, you can reserve itineraries (some websites do this for a small fee) and use that for VISA process. I did that for last time I visited Netherlands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Booking travel tickets for visa without paying?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6545/booking-travel-tickets-for-visa-without-paying) and [What ticket reservation do I need for a Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36568/what-ticket-reservation-do-i-need-for-a-schengen-visa)