# flight tickets for schengen visa application?

Tags: schengen

how do I get flight tickets for my schengen visa application without paying?
I have spoken to a travel agent and he said he can only 'reserve' it for 24 hours and after that its cancelled.
Will that still count as 'confirmed booking'?

I do not want to pay yet in case my application gets rejected.

Comment: Why do you believe you must have the  flight tickets when making the application? The application form does **not** ask for that information. Official information states that you must prove that you can **finance** the trip, but not that you already have the tickets.

Comment: You have asked this question before, but I see you’ve deleted it. Does this answer your question? [What ticket reservation do I need for a Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36568/what-ticket-reservation-do-i-need-for-a-schengen-visa)

Comment: not really, it says since you need insurance, you need to book tickets